# how to use boto3 create aws glue job with extra jar files?

Tags: boto3, aws-glue, vertica

I am trying to create a aws glue job from my python job with boto3 to access data in HP Vertica database. In order to do this I need to pass a Vertica driver jar file to the job.

I tried using --extra-jars but it seems not working. It reminds me the error of not able to find the driver java class. Can anyone help? The driver jar file I am using is vertica-jdbc-9.3.1-0.jar(763kb) and my current glue script looks like

```
myJob = glue.create_job(Name='james_test_glue_job', 
                        Role='some-good-glue',
                        Command={'Name': 'glueetl','ScriptLocation': 's3://path','PythonVersion': '3'},
                        Connections={'Connections': ['mssql connection']},
                        DefaultArguments={'--extra-py-files': 'pyfile-path', '--extra-jars': 'vertica-driver-path'},
                        MaxRetries=0,
                        MaxCapacity=12.0,
                        Timeout=2880,
                        GlueVersion='1.0'
                        )
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the issue, needed to give the `--extra-jars` in `start_job_run()` as well.

```
glue.start_job_run(JobName='your-job-name', Arguments={"--extra-jars": "s3://jar_path"})
```